# Block access to one method while another is called?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have 2 methods, one to add a message

```
addMessage
```

And one to get all messages and clear the list:

```
getMessagesToSendAndClear
```

Is it possible to allow multiple threads to call AddMessage at the same time, but keep calls "on hold" when getMessagesToSendAnClear is being called?

getMessagesToSendAnClear is only called by 1 thread.

With "on hold" i mean the same effect as when using synchronized.

I can't put synchronized in front of the methods cause than addMessage can only be called by 1 thread at a time.

[edit] I started thinking that getMessagesToSendAndClear may only be called when addMessage isn't called. Difficult one!

[edit] Maybe also interested is that my write method (addMessage) is very cheap and called very frequently and my read method (getMessagesToSendAnClear) is slow and called rarely.

Comment: Are you looking for a [Read-write lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)?

Comment: Going to take a peek at the javadoc and do a quick test. Cheers!

Comment: How about have a public Boolean running. Set it to false in the getMesage method at start and true when it ends. Then in addMessage do if(running){addMessage code} and while(!running){ do nothing}

Comment: @Tinus any reasons why you don't simply use one of the concurrent collections available in the JDK (for your use case a BlockingQueue would probably be a good match).

Comment: I agree with both Ordous and assylias - your question describes _how_ you envisage solving your problem, and when you describe it like that it's the canonical use case for a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, but if you step back and consider _what_ the problem is at a higher level then a `LinkedBlockingQueue` should solve it without needing any synchronization at all - `addMessage` would add items to the queue and `getMessagesToSendAndClear` would use `drainTo` to drain the queue into another list for processing.

Comment: Indeed, i remember that i used BlockingQueue once in the past. It has a really nice drainTo function that gets all items and clears the queue. And everything in a atomic way. Moving from Read-write javadoc to BlockingQueue javadoc. Cheers again!

Comment: @Tinus: Where did you get the information that `BlockingQueue#drainTo()` is atomic?

Comment: @Keppil: Indeed, i suspect that makes blockingqueue quite useless in my case, cause when a item is added to the blockinqueue while drainto is executed the behaviour is undefined, maybe the added item is lost? Not sure what undefined means in this case, but it doesn't sound it can't be trusted. Going to do a bit of searching on the subject.

Comment: No, the javadoc says that the behaviour of `drainTo` is undefined if there are any modifications to "the specified collection", i.e. the collection you are draining _into_, not the queue you're draining _from_.  As long as there are no exceptions thrown by the target collection when adding drained items then you can be sure that every message is either in the queue or in the drain collection, not both.

Comment: @Tinus: I interpreted it that way too first, but Ian is right. The `drainTo()` operation is still not atomic, but it should work fine for your usecase anyway.

Comment: @IanRoberts: thanks for the explanation, there was a bit of panic on my side thinking i had to rewrite old code :-) No problem Keppil , i did scan the javadoc after your comment and did read the same thing.